# My app will no longer run under Snow Leopard, runs fine under Lion

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, xcode4.3

My app will no longer run under Snow Leopard, even though it was originally written for Snow Leopard.  It runs fine on my Dev machine under Lion. But when I test it on my Snow Leopard Mac Mini the app starts but the window does not appear. Going to file, new window does nothing. My depolyment target is set to 10.6. Is there something I did to make my app lose Snow Leopard compatiblty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have added XIB files to the project and haven't turned off *Auto Layout* and set the deployment target to 10.6 within IB...

Comment: That worked! Thanks! The deployment target in IB was set to 10.7 and I changed it to 10.6 and now it works. I wasn't aware that IB also had a deployment target. It must have gotten changed when I added a popover that I didn't end up using.